# How to convert a date to string in format YYYYMMDD?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a date in a file with this format: `Sun Jan 28 01:00:22 2018`

but need to transform it into a `YYYYMMDD` format, for the date to be used as a `partition`.

I tried to use this command but the return I have is NULL.

```
select from_unixtime (unix_timestamp ('Sun Jan 28 01:00:22 2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `unix_timestamp` should specify the format of the string input, which is `E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy`.

Thereafter the argument to `from_unixtime` should specify the output format, which is `yyyyMMdd` in this case.

You should use

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Sun Jan 28 01:00:22 2018','E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy')
                     ,'yyyyMMdd'
                    )
```

[**`Documentation for useful patterns`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)